# Is there any other way to use different function name for __init__ in python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, init

for example:
for code like this,

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, N, weights):
```

can i write like this

```
class Solution:
    def snowball(self, N, weights):
```

if not then why?

Comment: *"can i write like this"* - No. *"if not then why?"* - Because that's how the language has been designed.

Comment: Magic methods cannot be overwritten by any other names.

Answer (score 0):

No this is a magic method of class, so you can't overwrite it. The snowball method you call is not a magic, and you can't "declare" it as a magic method. The snowball method is just a normal method of class's. You can't initialize a new instance with it.

For more (https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/magic-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why would you like to change the constructor method (**init**).
The **init** method lets the class initialize the object's attributes and serves no other purpose. Aditionally, as all the functions that starts with double underscore, the constructor method it's a special method and it's only purpose it's to construct the class.
If you are willing to change that name, you could rename it like:

```
__init__ = __newconstructorname__
```

You can check more info here:
https://www.udacity.com/blog/2021/11/__init__-in-python-an-overview.html